# Why is a JSON parsed as Uint8Array by MQTT.js?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I use [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) to retrieve messages from my `mosquitto` MQTT broker. It worked fine until I got to a specific message:

```
external/forecast {"latitude": 48.2376, "longitude": 2.5329, "timezone": "Europe/Paris", "currently": {"time": 1524566532, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 17.37, "apparentTemperature": 17.37, "dewPoint": 8.64, "humidity": 0.57, "pressure": 1019.35, "windSpeed": 3.67, "windGust": 3.78, "windBearing": 240, "cloudCover": 0.27, "uvIndex": 5, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 323.7}, "hourly": {"summary": "Nuages \u00e9pars d\u00e9butant dans l\u2019apr\u00e8s-midi.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "data": [{"time": 1524564000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 16.1, "apparentTemperature": 16.1, "dewPoint": 8.38, "humidity": 0.6, "pressure": 1019.69, "windSpeed": 3.6, "windGust": 3.75, "windBearing": 242, "cloudCover": 0.22, "uvIndex": 4, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 324.07}, {"time": 1524567600, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 17.91, "apparentTemperature": 17.91, "dewPoint": 8.73, "humidity": 0.55, "pressure": 1019.21, "windSpeed": 3.71, "windGust": 3.8, "windBearing": 238, "cloudCover": 0.29, "uvIndex": 5, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 323.55}, {"time": 1524571200, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 19.19, "apparentTemperature": 19.19, "dewPoint": 8.9, "humidity": 0.51, "pressure": 1018.62, "windSpeed": 3.67, "windGust": 3.75, "windBearing": 232, "cloudCover": 0.45, "uvIndex": 5, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 323.12}, {"time": 1524574800, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 20.2, "apparentTemperature": 20.2, "dewPoint": 8.9, "humidity": 0.48, "pressure": 1017.92, "windSpeed": 3.66, "windGust": 3.87, "windBearing": 227, "cloudCover": 0.59, "uvIndex": 4, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 322.65}, {"time": 1524578400, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 20.75, "apparentTemperature": 20.75, "dewPoint": 8.88, "humidity": 0.47, "pressure": 1017.11, "windSpeed": 3.79, "windGust": 4.3, "windBearing": 226, "cloudCover": 0.64, "uvIndex": 3, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 322.27}, {"time": 1524582000, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0076, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 21.04, "apparentTemperature": 21.04, "dewPoint": 8.89, "humidity": 0.46, "pressure": 1016.39, "windSpeed": 3.94, "windGust": 4.73, "windBearing": 227, "cloudCover": 0.6, "uvIndex": 2, "ozone": 322.03}, {"time": 1524585600, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0051, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 20.9, "apparentTemperature": 20.9, "dewPoint": 8.93, "humidity": 0.46, "pressure": 1015.8, "windSpeed": 3.89, "windGust": 5, "windBearing": 229, "cloudCover": 0.54, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 322.05}, {"time": 1524589200, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 20.46, "apparentTemperature": 20.46, "dewPoint": 8.96, "humidity": 0.48, "pressure": 1015.31, "windSpeed": 3.75, "windGust": 5.25, "windBearing": 232, "cloudCover": 0.46, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 322.17}, {"time": 1524592800, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 19.52, "apparentTemperature": 19.52, "dewPoint": 8.86, "humidity": 0.5, "pressure": 1014.97, "windSpeed": 3.68, "windGust": 5.68, "windBearing": 235, "cloudCover": 0.39, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 322.11}, {"time": 1524596400, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 18.67, "apparentTemperature": 18.67, "dewPoint": 8.41, "humidity": 0.51, "pressure": 1014.9, "windSpeed": 3.8, "windGust": 6.46, "windBearing": 236, "cloudCover": 0.32, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 321.52}, {"time": 1524600000, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 17.68, "apparentTemperature": 17.68, "dewPoint": 7.78, "humidity": 0.52, "pressure": 1014.98, "windSpeed": 3.98, "windGust": 7.41, "windBearing": 238, "cloudCover": 0.26, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.86}, {"time": 1524603600, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 16.98, "apparentTemperature": 16.98, "dewPoint": 7.44, "humidity": 0.53, "pressure": 1015.01, "windSpeed": 4.12, "windGust": 8.17, "windBearing": 240, "cloudCover": 0.22, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.3}, {"time": 1524607200, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 16.37, "apparentTemperature": 16.37, "dewPoint": 7.68, "humidity": 0.56, "pressure": 1014.9, "windSpeed": 4.19, "windGust": 8.63, "windBearing": 244, "cloudCover": 0.21, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.27}, {"time": 1524610800, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 15.61, "apparentTemperature": 15.61, "dewPoint": 8.19, "humidity": 0.61, "pressure": 1014.73, "windSpeed": 4.2, "windGust": 8.91, "windBearing": 246, "cloudCover": 0.22, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.43}, {"time": 1524614400, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 14.76, "apparentTemperature": 14.76, "dewPoint": 8.55, "humidity": 0.66, "pressure": 1014.6, "windSpeed": 4.16, "windGust": 9.01, "windBearing": 246, "cloudCover": 0.21, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.5}, {"time": 1524618000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 14.03, "apparentTemperature": 14.03, "dewPoint": 8.5, "humidity": 0.69, "pressure": 1014.53, "windSpeed": 3.72, "windGust": 8.89, "windBearing": 239, "cloudCover": 0.15, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.15}, {"time": 1524621600, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 13.51, "apparentTemperature": 13.51, "dewPoint": 8.29, "humidity": 0.71, "pressure": 1014.52, "windSpeed": 3.47, "windGust": 8.6, "windBearing": 265, "cloudCover": 0.06, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 319.69}, {"time": 1524625200, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 13.17, "apparentTemperature": 13.17, "dewPoint": 8.22, "humidity": 0.72, "pressure": 1014.61, "windSpeed": 3.42, "windGust": 8.32, "windBearing": 260, "cloudCover": 0.01, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 319.57}, {"time": 1524628800, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 12.34, "apparentTemperature": 12.34, "dewPoint": 8.33, "humidity": 0.77, "pressure": 1014.8, "windSpeed": 3.32, "windGust": 8.02, "windBearing": 267, "cloudCover": 0.02, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 320.2}, {"time": 1524632400, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 11.37, "apparentTemperature": 11.37, "dewPoint": 8.48, "humidity": 0.82, "pressure": 1015.08, "windSpeed": 3.43, "windGust": 7.73, "windBearing": 243, "cloudCover": 0.07, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 321.22}, {"time": 1524636000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 10.63, "apparentTemperature": 10.63, "dewPoint": 8.59, "humidity": 0.87, "pressure": 1015.43, "windSpeed": 3.74, "windGust": 7.63, "windBearing": 249, "cloudCover": 0.17, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 321.96}, {"time": 1524639600, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 10.86, "apparentTemperature": 10.86, "dewPoint": 8.85, "humidity": 0.87, "pressure": 1015.87, "windSpeed": 3.86, "windGust": 7.92, "windBearing": 252, "cloudCover": 0.34, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 322.31}, {"time": 1524643200, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0152, "precipProbability": 0.03, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 11.83, "apparentTemperature": 11.83, "dewPoint": 9.18, "humidity": 0.84, "pressure": 1016.38, "windSpeed": 4.02, "windGust": 8.39, "windBearing": 282, "cloudCover": 0.56, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 322.42}, {"time": 1524646800, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0305, "precipProbability": 0.03, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 13.17, "apparentTemperature": 13.17, "dewPoint": 9.25, "humidity": 0.77, "pressure": 1016.79, "windSpeed": 4.5, "windGust": 8.65, "windBearing": 260, "cloudCover": 0.73, "uvIndex": 2, "ozone": 322.23}, {"time": 1524650400, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0457, "precipProbability": 0.04, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 13.94, "apparentTemperature": 13.94, "dewPoint": 9, "humidity": 0.72, "pressure": 1017.06, "windSpeed": 4.19, "windGust": 8.42, "windBearing": 176, "cloudCover": 0.82, "uvIndex": 3, "ozone": 321.54}, {"time": 1524654000, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0635, "precipProbability": 0.04, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 14.41, "apparentTemperature": 14.41, "dewPoint": 8.55, "humidity": 0.68, "pressure": 1017.24, "windSpeed": 4.08, "windGust": 7.98, "windBearing": 5, "cloudCover": 0.86, "uvIndex": 4, "ozone": 320.64}, {"time": 1524657600, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0686, "precipProbability": 0.04, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 14.47, "apparentTemperature": 14.47, "dewPoint": 8.03, "humidity": 0.65, "pressure": 1017.33, "windSpeed": 4.74, "windGust": 7.67, "windBearing": 285, "cloudCover": 0.84, "uvIndex": 4, "ozone": 320.02}, {"time": 1524661200, "summary": "Nuageux", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0508, "precipProbability": 0.03, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 14.96, "apparentTemperature": 14.96, "dewPoint": 7.42, "humidity": 0.61, "pressure": 1017.27, "windSpeed": 4.92, "windGust": 7.68, "windBearing": 273, "cloudCover": 0.71, "uvIndex": 4, "ozone": 320.02}, {"time": 1524664800, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0254, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 15.56, "apparentTemperature": 15.56, "dewPoint": 6.73, "humidity": 0.56, "pressure": 1017.15, "windSpeed": 5.14, "windGust": 7.83, "windBearing": 276, "cloudCover": 0.51, "uvIndex": 3, "ozone": 320.43}, {"time": 1524668400, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0178, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 15.88, "apparentTemperature": 15.88, "dewPoint": 6.11, "humidity": 0.52, "pressure": 1017.11, "windSpeed": 5.28, "windGust": 7.96, "windBearing": 287, "cloudCover": 0.38, "uvIndex": 2, "ozone": 320.99}, {"time": 1524672000, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0152, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 15.43, "apparentTemperature": 15.43, "dewPoint": 5.62, "humidity": 0.52, "pressure": 1017.22, "windSpeed": 5.25, "windGust": 7.96, "windBearing": 291, "cloudCover": 0.39, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 321.78}, {"time": 1524675600, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0152, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 14.5, "apparentTemperature": 14.5, "dewPoint": 5.19, "humidity": 0.54, "pressure": 1017.42, "windSpeed": 5.13, "windGust": 7.94, "windBearing": 294, "cloudCover": 0.46, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 322.75}, {"time": 1524679200, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "precipIntensity": 0.0152, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 13.33, "apparentTemperature": 13.33, "dewPoint": 4.79, "humidity": 0.56, "pressure": 1017.78, "windSpeed": 4.9, "windGust": 7.98, "windBearing": 298, "cloudCover": 0.47, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 323.73}, {"time": 1524682800, "summary": "Nuages \u00c9pars", "icon": "partly-cloudy-night", "precipIntensity": 0.0102, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperature": 12.49, "apparentTemperature": 12.49, "dewPoint": 4.34, "humidity": 0.58, "pressure": 1018.35, "windSpeed": 4.55, "windGust": 8.16, "windBearing": 292, "cloudCover": 0.34, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 324.54}, {"time": 1524686400, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 11.78, "apparentTemperature": 11.78, "dewPoint": 3.89, "humidity": 0.58, "pressure": 1019.05, "windSpeed": 4.1, "windGust": 8.41, "windBearing": 284, "cloudCover": 0.15, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 325.24}, {"time": 1524690000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 11.31, "apparentTemperature": 11.31, "dewPoint": 3.6, "humidity": 0.59, "pressure": 1019.64, "windSpeed": 3.77, "windGust": 8.67, "windBearing": 295, "cloudCover": 0.02, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 326.25}, {"time": 1524693600, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 10.67, "apparentTemperature": 10.67, "dewPoint": 3.57, "humidity": 0.61, "pressure": 1019.99, "windSpeed": 3.63, "windGust": 8.97, "windBearing": 339, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 327.44}, {"time": 1524697200, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 9.72, "apparentTemperature": 7.86, "dewPoint": 3.67, "humidity": 0.66, "pressure": 1020.19, "windSpeed": 3.59, "windGust": 9.28, "windBearing": 227, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 328.92}, {"time": 1524700800, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 8.59, "apparentTemperature": 6.47, "dewPoint": 3.8, "humidity": 0.72, "pressure": 1020.34, "windSpeed": 3.61, "windGust": 9.44, "windBearing": 271, "cloudCover": 0.01, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 330.94}, {"time": 1524704400, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 7.55, "apparentTemperature": 5.44, "dewPoint": 3.86, "humidity": 0.77, "pressure": 1020.41, "windSpeed": 3.2, "windGust": 9.37, "windBearing": 298, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 333.94}, {"time": 1524708000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 6.83, "apparentTemperature": 4.61, "dewPoint": 3.93, "humidity": 0.82, "pressure": 1020.4, "windSpeed": 3.14, "windGust": 9.16, "windBearing": 238, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 337.46}, {"time": 1524711600, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 6.59, "apparentTemperature": 4, "dewPoint": 4.01, "humidity": 0.84, "pressure": 1020.47, "windSpeed": 3.66, "windGust": 8.88, "windBearing": 261, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 340.79}, {"time": 1524715200, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-night", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 6.61, "apparentTemperature": 4.49, "dewPoint": 4.16, "humidity": 0.84, "pressure": 1020.69, "windSpeed": 2.92, "windGust": 8.55, "windBearing": 304, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 344.13}, {"time": 1524718800, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 6.79, "apparentTemperature": 4.33, "dewPoint": 4.34, "humidity": 0.84, "pressure": 1021, "windSpeed": 3.51, "windGust": 8.14, "windBearing": 246, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 347.31}, {"time": 1524722400, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 7.35, "apparentTemperature": 4.75, "dewPoint": 4.47, "humidity": 0.82, "pressure": 1021.28, "windSpeed": 3.99, "windGust": 7.71, "windBearing": 261, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 0, "ozone": 349.4}, {"time": 1524726000, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 8.63, "apparentTemperature": 6.31, "dewPoint": 4.52, "humidity": 0.75, "pressure": 1021.52, "windSpeed": 4.01, "windGust": 7.17, "windBearing": 168, "cloudCover": 0, "uvIndex": 1, "ozone": 349.71}, {"time": 1524729600, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 10.39, "apparentTemperature": 10.39, "dewPoint": 4.53, "humidity": 0.67, "pressure": 1021.72, "windSpeed": 4.04, "windGust": 6.62, "windBearing": 25, "cloudCover": 0.01, "uvIndex": 2, "ozone": 348.94}, {"time": 1524733200, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 12.13, "apparentTemperature": 12.13, "dewPoint": 4.47, "humidity": 0.59, "pressure": 1021.81, "windSpeed": 4.06, "windGust": 6.25, "windBearing": 281, "cloudCover": 0.02, "uvIndex": 3, "ozone": 348.1}, {"time": 1524736800, "summary": "D\u00e9gag\u00e9", "icon": "clear-day", "precipIntensity": 0, "precipProbability": 0, "temperature": 13.42, "apparentTemperature": 13.42, "dewPoint": 4.25, "humidity": 0.54, "pressure": 1021.74, "windSpeed": 4.16, "windGust": 6.28, "windBearing": 270, "cloudCover": 0.02, "uvIndex": 4, "ozone": 347.73}]}, "daily": {"summary": "Pluie faible dimanche, avec des temp\u00e9ratures maximales descendant jusqu\u2019\u00e0 12\u00b0C lundi.", "icon": "rain", "data": [{"time": 1524520800, "summary": "Nuages \u00e9pars durant toute la journ\u00e9e.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "sunriseTime": 1524545075, "sunsetTime": 1524596216, "moonPhase": 0.31, "precipIntensity": 0.0025, "precipIntensityMax": 0.0076, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524582000, "precipProbability": 0.05, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 21.04, "temperatureHighTime": 1524582000, "temperatureLow": 10.63, "temperatureLowTime": 1524636000, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 21.04, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524582000, "apparentTemperatureLow": 10.63, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1524636000, "dewPoint": 7.69, "humidity": 0.66, "pressure": 1018.52, "windSpeed": 2.63, "windGust": 8.17, "windGustTime": 1524603600, "windBearing": 238, "cloudCover": 0.51, "uvIndex": 5, "uvIndexTime": 1524567600, "visibility": 10.01, "ozone": 326.83, "temperatureMin": 7.54, "temperatureMinTime": 1524546000, "temperatureMax": 21.04, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524582000, "apparentTemperatureMin": 6.65, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524542400, "apparentTemperatureMax": 21.04, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524582000}, {"time": 1524607200, "summary": "Nuages \u00e9pars jusque dans la soir\u00e9e.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "sunriseTime": 1524631366, "sunsetTime": 1524682706, "moonPhase": 0.34, "precipIntensity": 0.0152, "precipIntensityMax": 0.0686, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524657600, "precipProbability": 0.12, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 15.88, "temperatureHighTime": 1524668400, "temperatureLow": 6.59, "temperatureLowTime": 1524711600, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 15.88, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524668400, "apparentTemperatureLow": 4, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1524711600, "dewPoint": 7.31, "humidity": 0.67, "pressure": 1016.45, "windSpeed": 3.66, "windGust": 9.01, "windGustTime": 1524614400, "windBearing": 271, "cloudCover": 0.36, "uvIndex": 4, "uvIndexTime": 1524654000, "ozone": 321.62, "temperatureMin": 10.63, "temperatureMinTime": 1524636000, "temperatureMax": 16.37, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524607200, "apparentTemperatureMin": 10.63, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524636000, "apparentTemperatureMax": 16.37, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524607200}, {"time": 1524693600, "summary": "Nuageux d\u00e9butant dans l\u2019apr\u00e8s-midi.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-night", "sunriseTime": 1524717658, "sunsetTime": 1524769195, "moonPhase": 0.38, "precipIntensity": 0.0051, "precipIntensityMax": 0.0152, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524747600, "precipProbability": 0.05, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 14.38, "temperatureHighTime": 1524744000, "temperatureLow": 6.91, "temperatureLowTime": 1524805200, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 14.38, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524744000, "apparentTemperatureLow": 5.14, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1524808800, "dewPoint": 4.03, "humidity": 0.65, "pressure": 1020.6, "windSpeed": 2.62, "windGust": 9.44, "windGustTime": 1524700800, "windBearing": 277, "cloudCover": 0.34, "uvIndex": 6, "uvIndexTime": 1524740400, "ozone": 342.34, "temperatureMin": 6.59, "temperatureMinTime": 1524711600, "temperatureMax": 14.38, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524744000, "apparentTemperatureMin": 4, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524711600, "apparentTemperatureMax": 14.38, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524744000}, {"time": 1524780000, "summary": "Nuageux durant toute la journ\u00e9e.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "sunriseTime": 1524803952, "sunsetTime": 1524855684, "moonPhase": 0.42, "precipIntensity": 0.0051, "precipIntensityMax": 0.0279, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524862800, "precipProbability": 0.02, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 15.09, "temperatureHighTime": 1524830400, "temperatureLow": 7.75, "temperatureLowTime": 1524891600, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 15.09, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524830400, "apparentTemperatureLow": 5.97, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1524895200, "dewPoint": 5, "humidity": 0.64, "pressure": 1012.76, "windSpeed": 2.13, "windGust": 6.54, "windGustTime": 1524841200, "windBearing": 155, "cloudCover": 0.86, "uvIndex": 4, "uvIndexTime": 1524830400, "ozone": 351.55, "temperatureMin": 6.91, "temperatureMinTime": 1524805200, "temperatureMax": 15.09, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524830400, "apparentTemperatureMin": 5.14, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524808800, "apparentTemperatureMax": 15.09, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524830400}, {"time": 1524866400, "summary": "Nuageux durant toute la journ\u00e9e.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "sunriseTime": 1524890246, "sunsetTime": 1524942174, "moonPhase": 0.45, "precipIntensity": 0.0229, "precipIntensityMax": 0.1092, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524949200, "precipProbability": 0.19, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 15.19, "temperatureHighTime": 1524931200, "temperatureLow": 7.52, "temperatureLowTime": 1524981600, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 15.19, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524931200, "apparentTemperatureLow": 5.04, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1524981600, "dewPoint": 6.97, "humidity": 0.71, "pressure": 1008.98, "windSpeed": 2.81, "windGust": 4.55, "windGustTime": 1524898800, "windBearing": 189, "cloudCover": 0.85, "uvIndex": 3, "uvIndexTime": 1524909600, "ozone": 343.92, "temperatureMin": 7.75, "temperatureMinTime": 1524891600, "temperatureMax": 15.19, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524931200, "apparentTemperatureMin": 5.97, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524895200, "apparentTemperatureMax": 15.19, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524931200}, {"time": 1524952800, "summary": "Pluie faible dans la matin\u00e9e et soir\u00e9e.", "icon": "rain", "sunriseTime": 1524976542, "sunsetTime": 1525028663, "moonPhase": 0.48, "precipIntensity": 0.4775, "precipIntensityMax": 1.0897, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1524981600, "precipProbability": 0.8, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 12.17, "temperatureHighTime": 1524999600, "temperatureLow": 5.89, "temperatureLowTime": 1525064400, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 12.17, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1524999600, "apparentTemperatureLow": 3.16, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1525064400, "dewPoint": 8.47, "humidity": 0.86, "pressure": 1003.05, "windSpeed": 0.7, "windGust": 10.81, "windGustTime": 1524985200, "windBearing": 62, "cloudCover": 0.9, "uvIndex": 3, "uvIndexTime": 1524999600, "ozone": 362.25, "temperatureMin": 7.52, "temperatureMinTime": 1524981600, "temperatureMax": 12.48, "temperatureMaxTime": 1524952800, "apparentTemperatureMin": 5.04, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1524981600, "apparentTemperatureMax": 12.48, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1524952800}, {"time": 1525039200, "summary": "Nuageux durant toute la journ\u00e9e.", "icon": "partly-cloudy-day", "sunriseTime": 1525062839, "sunsetTime": 1525115151, "moonPhase": 0.52, "precipIntensity": 0.2515, "precipIntensityMax": 0.6883, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1525053600, "precipProbability": 0.6, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 11.86, "temperatureHighTime": 1525086000, "temperatureLow": 7.74, "temperatureLowTime": 1525143600, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 11.86, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1525086000, "apparentTemperatureLow": 6.34, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1525143600, "dewPoint": 6.71, "humidity": 0.83, "pressure": 1009.12, "windSpeed": 3.29, "windGust": 8.43, "windGustTime": 1525039200, "windBearing": 244, "cloudCover": 0.81, "uvIndex": 3, "uvIndexTime": 1525086000, "ozone": 388.37, "temperatureMin": 5.89, "temperatureMinTime": 1525064400, "temperatureMax": 11.86, "temperatureMaxTime": 1525086000, "apparentTemperatureMin": 3.16, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1525064400, "apparentTemperatureMax": 11.86, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1525086000}, {"time": 1525125600, "summary": "Couvert durant toute la journ\u00e9e.", "icon": "cloudy", "sunriseTime": 1525149138, "sunsetTime": 1525201640, "moonPhase": 0.55, "precipIntensity": 0.0559, "precipIntensityMax": 0.2565, "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1525186800, "precipProbability": 0.26, "precipType": "rain", "temperatureHigh": 12.77, "temperatureHighTime": 1525176000, "temperatureLow": 5.94, "temperatureLowTime": 1525237200, "apparentTemperatureHigh": 12.77, "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1525176000, "apparentTemperatureLow": 5.12, "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1525237200, "dewPoint": 5.68, "humidity": 0.72, "pressure": 1014.78, "windSpeed": 1.01, "windGust": 8.56, "windGustTime": 1525136400, "windBearing": 103, "cloudCover": 1, "uvIndex": 3, "uvIndexTime": 1525172400, "ozone": 387.67, "temperatureMin": 7.74, "temperatureMinTime": 1525143600, "temperatureMax": 12.77, "temperatureMaxTime": 1525176000, "apparentTemperatureMin": 6.34, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1525143600, "apparentTemperatureMax": 12.77, "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1525176000}]}, "flags": {"sources": ["isd", "cmc", "gfs", "madis"], "isd-stations": ["070380-34061", "070530-99999", "070570-99999", "071430-99999", "071450-99999", "071470-99999", "071480-99999", "071490-99999", "071500-99999", "071530-99999", "071540-99999", "071560-99999", "071570-99999", "071813-99999", "074765-99999", "999999-34061"], "units": "si"}, "offset": 2}
```

This is how the message is seen at the broker level, and is a correctly formatted JSON dictionary.

On the client (browser) I retrieve it in a Vue component and fire a callback once a message is received on the `external/forecast` topic. The first line of this callback logs the message to the console (prior to any transformation).

The logged message is of type `Uint8Array` and shows as (I truncated the middle part as the body of my question was too large)

```
Uint8Array(26840) [123, 34, 108, 97, 116, 105, 116, 117, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 52, 56, 46, 56, 50, 51, 50, 57, 57, 44, 32, 34, 108, 111, 110, 103, 105, 116, 117, 100, 101, 34, 58, 32, 50, 46, 49, 50, 49, 50, 48, 49, 44, 32, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 122, 111, 110, 101, 34, 58, 32, 34, 69, 117, 114, 111, 112, 101, 47, 80, 97, 114, 105, 115, 34, 44, 32, 34, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 108, 121, 34, 58, 32, 123, 34, 116, 105, 109, 101, 34, 58, 32, 49, 53, 50, …][0 … 9999][0 … 99]0: 1231: 342: 1083: 974: 1165: 1056: 1167: 1178: 1009: 10110: 3411: 5812: 3213: 5214: 5615: 4616: 5617: 5018: 5119: 5020: 5721: 5722: 4423: 3224: 3425: 10826: 11127: 11028: 10329: 10530: 11631: 11732: 10033: 10134: 3435: 5836: 3237: 5038: 4639: 4940: 5041: 4942: 5043: 4844: 4945: 4446: 3247: 3448: 11649: 10550: 10951: 10152: 12253: 11154: 11055: 10156: 3457: 5858: 3259: 3460: 6961: 11762: 11463: 11164: 11265: 10166: 4767: 8068: 9769: 11470: 10571: 11572: 3473: 4474: 3275: 3476: 9977: 11778: 11479: 11480: 10181: 11082: 11683: 10884: 12185: 3486: 5887: 3288: 12389: 3490: 11691: 10592: 10993: 10194: 3495: 5896: 3297: 4998: 5399: 50[100 … 199][200 … 299][300 … 399][400 … 499][500 … 599][600 … 699][700 … 799][800 … 899][900 … 999][1000 … 1099][1100 … 1199][1200 … 1299][1300 … 1399][1400 … 1499][1500 … 1599][1600 … 1699][1700 … 1799][1800 … 1899][1900 … 1999][2000 … 2099][2100 … 2199][2200 … 2299][2300 … 2399][2400 … 2499][2500 … 2599][2600 … 2699][2700 … 2799][2800 … 2899][2900 … 2999][3000 … 3099][3100 … 3199][3200 … 3299][3300 … 3399][3400 … 3499][3500 … 3599][3600 … 3699][3700 … 3799][3800 … 3899][3900 … 3999][4000 … 4099][4100 … 4199][4200 … 4299][4300 … 4399][4400 … 4499][4500 … 4599][4600 … 4699][4700 … 4799][4800 … 4899]
(...)
[9100 … 9199][9200 … 9299][9300 … 9399][9400 … 9499][9500 … 9599][9600 … 9699][9700 … 9799][9800 … 9899][9900 … 9999][10000 … 19999][20000 … 26839]
```

**It means that MQTT.js has not correctly retrieved it. Why?**

Please note that I have other topics which I query with MQTT.js without problems.

This includes single elements (such as an int), or JSON strings (such as the one above, though smaller). So the usage of MQTT.js itself is not the question, rather why it processes the message incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All MQTT message payloads are just byte arrays at the transport level. If any client library is automatically converting payloads that look like strings to strings this is most likely based on a default encoding (most likely UTF-8)

That JSON contains UTF-16 chars ("`Nuages \u00e9pars d\u00e9butant dans l\u2019apr\u00e8s...`") and I would guess that the UTF-8 decoder is failing so the client library is returning the byte representation you to do your own decoding:

```
var decoded = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(message)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I will add to your answer the solution I used.